# HTML5 video player audio/video gradually unsync

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, video, flash, html5

I've been struggling with this issue for a long time now.  It happened after a fresh OS install of Windows 10.  Basically, as an HTML5 video plays, the audio and the video gradually unsync.  The video is also pretty choppy.  This does not happen if I force the flash player to be used, so I'm positive at this point it is a software issue.

I tried turning on all the chrome://flags that deal with hardware video decode, as well as turning them all off with no luck.  I thought maybe it was my 5.1 receiver and/or TV, but that can't be the case since the flash player works fine (as far as the video/audio not desyncing, but there's other issues with the flash player, like hidden ads playing when playing a YouTube video, but that might be because of the forced flash player hack).

I also tried Canary, but that has the same issue.  Firefox and IE have the same issue as well, so maybe this is a webkit issue?

TV is running in 4K, and I've tried a bunch of different refresh rates.  The refresh rate seems to change how long it takes to desync.  I also have tried to change the audio quality, and when changing it while the video is playing, it resyncs correctly, but then desyncs eventually again.

I've tried to change the audio buffer, but it just causes Chrome to crash it seems, and it seems like that fix is outdated by a few years anyways.

It can't be my machine.  It's honestly a beast, and I've posted the configs below.  I've updated all the drivers to the ones provided by the manufacturer. 
Chrome version 58.0.3029.110; 64-bit of course.

```
------------------
System Information
------------------
      Time of this report: 6/8/2017, 08:56:46
             Machine name: GOGETA
               Machine Id: {C67E0F28-9FB7-4343-BC75-C72A20088EF5}
         Operating System: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit (10.0, Build 15063) (15063.rs2_release.170317-1834)
                 Language: English (Regional Setting: English)
      System Manufacturer: MSI
             System Model: MS-7998
                     BIOS: BIOS Date: 01/21/16 13:54:42 Ver: V2.10
                Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E3-1275 v5 @ 3.60GHz (8 CPUs), ~3.6GHz
                   Memory: 65536MB RAM
      Available OS Memory: 65496MB RAM
                Page File: 9872MB used, 65351MB available
              Windows Dir: C:\WINDOWS
          DirectX Version: DirectX 12
      DX Setup Parameters: Not found
         User DPI Setting: Using System DPI
       System DPI Setting: 288 DPI (300 percent)
          DWM DPI Scaling: UnKnown
                 Miracast: Available, with HDCP
Microsoft Graphics Hybrid: Not Supported
           DxDiag Version: 10.00.15063.0000 64bit Unicode

------------
DxDiag Notes
------------
      Display Tab 1: No problems found.
        Sound Tab 1: No problems found.
          Input Tab: No problems found.

--------------------
DirectX Debug Levels
--------------------
Direct3D:    0/4 (retail)
DirectDraw:  0/4 (retail)
DirectInput: 0/5 (retail)
DirectMusic: 0/5 (retail)
DirectPlay:  0/9 (retail)
DirectSound: 0/5 (retail)
DirectShow:  0/6 (retail)

---------------
Display Devices
---------------
          Card name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti
       Manufacturer: NVIDIA
          Chip type: GeForce GTX 980 Ti
           DAC type: Integrated RAMDAC
        Device Type: Full Device
         Device Key: Enum\PCI\VEN_10DE&DEV_17C8&SUBSYS_855B1043&REV_A1
      Device Status: 0180200A [DN_DRIVER_LOADED|DN_STARTED|DN_DISABLEABLE|DN_NT_ENUMERATOR|DN_NT_DRIVER] 
Device Problem Code: No Problem
Driver Problem Code: Unknown
     Display Memory: 38851 MB
   Dedicated Memory: 6103 MB
      Shared Memory: 32747 MB
       Current Mode: 1920 x 1200 (32 bit) (32Hz)
        Driver Name: C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_7209bde3180ef5f7\nvldumdx.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_7209bde3180ef5f7\nvldumdx.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_7209bde3180ef5f7\nvldumdx.dll,C:\WINDOWS\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\nv_dispi.inf_amd64_7209bde3180ef5f7\nvldumdx.dll
Driver File Version: 22.21.0013.8233 (English)
     Driver Version: 22.21.13.8233
        DDI Version: 12
     Feature Levels: 12_1,12_0,11_1,11_0,10_1,10_0,9_3,9_2,9_1
       Driver Model: WDDM 2.2
Graphics Preemption: DMA
 Compute Preemption: DMA
           Miracast: Not Supported
Hybrid Graphics GPU: Not Supported
     Power P-states: Not Supported
  Driver Attributes: Final Retail
   Driver Date/Size: 5/16/2017 8:00:00 PM, 885216 bytes
        WHQL Logo'd: Yes
    WHQL Date Stamp: Unknown
  Device Identifier: {D7B71E3E-5488-11CF-DA53-56A51BC2DB35}
          Vendor ID: 0x10DE
          Device ID: 0x17C8
          SubSys ID: 0x855B1043
        Revision ID: 0x00A1
 Driver Strong Name: oem17.inf:0f066de3672d1ed2:Section088:22.21.13.8233:pci\ven_10de&dev_17c8
     Rank Of Driver: 00D12001
        Video Accel: Unknown
        DXVA2 Modes: DXVA2_ModeMPEG2_VLD  DXVA2_ModeVC1_D2010  DXVA2_ModeVC1_VLD  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_Stereo_Progressive_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_Stereo_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeH264_VLD_NoFGT  DXVA2_ModeHEVC_VLD_Main  DXVA2_ModeMPEG4pt2_VLD_Simple  DXVA2_ModeMPEG4pt2_VLD_AdvSimple_NoGMC  
      Deinterlace Caps: n/a
       D3D9 Overlay: Supported
            DXVA-HD: Supported
       DDraw Status: Not Available
         D3D Status: Enabled
         AGP Status: Not Available
           MPO Caps: Not Supported
        MPO Stretch: Not Supported
    MPO Media Hints: Not Supported
        MPO Formats: Not Supported

-------------
Sound Devices
-------------
            Description: Remote Audio
 Default Sound Playback: Yes
 Default Voice Playback: Yes
            Hardware ID: 
        Manufacturer ID: 1
             Product ID: 100
                   Type: WDM
            Driver Name: {3.0.0.00000001}.{6C26BA7D-F0B2-4225-B422-8168C5261E45}
         Driver Version:  ()
      Driver Attributes: Final Retail
            WHQL Logo'd: No
          Date and Size: , 0 bytes
            Other Files: 
        Driver Provider: 
         HW Accel Level: Basic
              Cap Flags: 0xF1F
    Min/Max Sample Rate: 100, 200000
Static/Strm HW Mix Bufs: 1, 0
 Static/Strm HW 3D Bufs: 0, 0
              HW Memory: 0
       Voice Management: No
 EAX(tm) 2.0 Listen/Src: No, No
   I3DL2(tm) Listen/Src: No, No
Sensaura(tm) ZoomFX(tm): No
```

Answer (score 0):

Available in chrome extensions from the web store It is an extension that corrects the playing of html5 video with flash  the problem occurs when flash tries to override html5' memory space.      HTML5 Flash Warning Fix for YouTube™ is the extension name.  This has worked for me and I have been using it for a while  Hope it works for u Good Luck
Gordon McIntosh